# How do your mods on your Warframe effect your Archwing stats?

Tags: warframe

I know you can apply mods to your Warframes, and to your Archwings, but how do the ones on your Warframe effect the stats on your Archwings? Which ones effect both your Warframe and your Archwing and which ones don't (I would prefer if you made one list, of the smaller category).

Comment: As far as I know, the only mods that will be of use are defensive ones (redirection, steel fiber, etc) since the archwings have their own mod system. I haven't gotten deeper into it because they're really not worth doing after you've gotten limbo.

Comment: @slow_excellence, J3 is coming back now, in his own Archwing boss fight! It seems like thier use is going to go back up now.

Comment: yeah I'm pretty excited about the new hybrid bossfight. I just hope that it's not as tedious as the fomorians were.

Comment: I was hyped for the Fororians, but it was a big let down. BUT, after watching the devstream and reading the patch nots, I have a feeling it will be epic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Changes in Update 15.6.0](https://forums.warframe.com/index.php?/topic/363216-update-1560/)** have resulted in some fairly hefty overhauls to the Archwing mod system.

> **Buffed Mods**
>
> - Critical Chance Mods for Archwing melee and rifles have been buffed.
> - Health/Shield/Armor Mods for Archwing have been buffed.
>
> **Overall Archwing Changes:**
>
> - Warframe Stats and Mods no longer carry over onto Archwing performance.  All Warframes will now perform equally well while piloting an Archwing, eliminating the need to use a specific Warframe for optimum Space Ninja performance.
> - All Archwings now have different base Health/Shield/Armor stats that can be modded (with the newly buffed Mods).

Unfortunately, this means that none of the Warframe mods effect Archwing stats any more.

Comment: no energy efficiency?

Comment: Nope, that's covered by [System Reroute](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/System_Reroute), one of the many new Archwing mods.

Comment: Answer updated for recent patches.

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer is slightly incorrect:

- Warframe aura mods carry over to the Archwing

  - Energy Siphon will allow your Archwing to gradually regenerate Energy
  - Rejuvenation will allow your Archwing to gradually regenerate Health.
  - Steel Charge will affect melee damage
  - Enemy Detector and Loot Detector will show enemies and drops around you, respectively
  - Rifle Amp will affect your rifle damage

  Some exceptions:

  - Ammo Aura mods (ones that increase the chance to find ammo) obviously do not work, as there is no "limited ammo" in Archwing.
  - Infested Impedance does not have a use yet

Comment: Are those the only two Auras?

Comment: @ShadowZ. I haven't fully tested out the effects of the other auras, so I'm going to refrain from updating the answer until I dive in the game later tonight to test it out

Comment: Hm. It was in my original answer, but I obviously failed to keep it when I changed for 15.6. Sorry about that! From my previous testing, most auras work. I'll dig out the list.

Comment: @ShadowZ. Updated the answer, hope it helps you out